# How to 'add' two numbers using a bitwise operator?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I have two numbers, and either can be any number. I want to add those numbers together, but in a special "binary" way.

So suppose I have the following two numbers: `7` and `9`. In their binary form they are:

```
0111 = 7
1001 = 9
```

I need a way to add `7` and `9` together in their binary form, but only where the two bits differ. If they differ, then the different bit should be set to a `1`.

With the example of `7` and `9`, the result I want is:

```
0111 = 7
1001 = 9
---- +
1111
```

Is there a way to perform such an operation in PHP?

Comment: Actually, 7+9=16 which is 10000 in binary.

Comment: `If they differ, then the different bit should be set to a 1‍‍` Then why the last digit is `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: Do you mean binary or? I.e. each bit that is 1 in at least one of the numbers is 1 in the result? This would mean the result of your operation on the inputs 0011 and 1010 would be 1011. If yes, you really probably mean binary or.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

```
$result = 7 | 9;
```

Answer (score 3):

> If they differ, then **the different bit should be set to a 1‍‍**

What you are asking is called bitwise exclusive OR

```
echo 7^9; 
// = 1110
```

But you are showing it should be `1111` which is actually bitwise OR,

```
echo 7|9
// = 1111
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description asks for a bitwise XOR, but the example you give demonstrates a regular bitwise OR. Before you can solve any problem, you need to clearly define it.